# sql server bulk insert and temporary tables

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

Ive been learning MYSQL but decided to have an attempt at SQL SERVER. I have basically just pasted the code from MYSQL to SQL SERVER and figuring out which parts of the code need to be adapted to work in SQL SERVER. I am trying to create a temporary table and do a bulk insert from a text file into this temporary table. this statement works fine in MYSQL as show:

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test123
    (
    Reason_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    Month_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    Year_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    Week_Type_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    accident_time_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    Alcohol_Level_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    Age_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    Gender_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL);

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\jon\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\roadsafety_test123.txt' 
     INTO TABLE test123
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
     LINES STARTING BY '' TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
     IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

and in SQL SERVER I have so far come up with this:

```
    DECLARE @test123 TABLE
    (
    Reason_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    Month_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    Year_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    Week_Type_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    accident_time_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    Alcohol_Level_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    Age_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    Gender_t VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL);

    BULK INSERT test123 FROM   'C:\\Users\\jon\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\roadsafety_test123.txt' 
    WITH (  FIELDTERMINATOR =',', FIRSTROW = 2, ROWTERMINATOR = '\N');
```

the query in SQL SERVER does not work however, the temporary table actions don't seem to be as straight forward as MYSQL and im struggling to find relevant information regarding it. I did aswell try creating the test123 table with a standard CREATE TABLE statement insert but I still got error 4863 for age_t column in test123, as far as the data goes I see no problems and it works perfectly fine in MYSQL.

I'm sure I have missed something obvious or done something the wrong way round as said I have never really used SQL SERVER before but can't find any definitive answers.

Comment: Why don't you temporarily extend Age_T to `VARCHAR(4000)`, then import the data and inspect it.

Comment: 1) Always include **the exact error message** in your question. 2) `DECLARE @test123 TABLE(...` declares a TABLE variable which is not the same as a temporary table in SQL Server terminology. A TABLE variable is temporary (English language) but behaves different from a temporary table (SQL Server teminology)

Comment: Also, your ROWTERMINATOR is differing from the one you used in the MySQL version (`'\n'` instead of `'\r\n'`). Also, try to remove lines from your `roadsafety_test123.txt` file until it has one or more rows that fail the BULK INSERT statement, then post that file as well -> format the contents using `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

You should also provide at least a few lines of the file you would use to import, it might help others to pinpoint what could be causing the error. :)

```
BULK INSERT test123 FROM 'C:\\Users\\jon\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\roadsafety_test123.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR =',', FIRSTROW = 2);
```

Just an idea, could you try removing the "ROWTERMINATOR = '\N'" part of the code. Bulk Insert in SQL Server treats the "end-of-line" as the default row terminator. And I read somewhere that Windows Text Files uses a different end-of-line symbols, **CR LF**, to mark the end of a row. Though I can't find the reference, you can see for it yourself by opening a text file with Notepad++, Click the **View** tab, **Show Symbol**, then ticking **Show End-of-Line**.

Comment: @Paritosh, My answer would be:

*BULK INSERT test123 FROM 'C:\\Users\\jon\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\roadsafety_test123.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR =',', FIRSTROW = 2);*

As I have tried suggesting to remove said part of the code. I hope that clear things up. I apologize for I am quite new here.

Comment: @Randloph   Thanks mate this did work perfectly afterwards, although I am a bit thrown as SQL SERVER seems to be able to determine when to terminate a row on text files only seemingly

Comment: @JonathanClark Glad to help. :)